# How to elegantly write multiple if-else conditions in SAS?

Tags: if-statement, macros, sas, conditional-statements

I have the following if-else conditions within a SAS macro:

```
%if &restart_flg = Y %then %do;
%if %sysfunc(exist(&library.f2)) %then %do;
proc sql;
Connect to xxxxx as dbcon (user=xx pw=xx server=xx port=xxx database=xxxxx);

select * into :prcs_flag_cnt    
from connection to dbcon  (
select count(1)::smallint
from &library.f2
where flag = 1 and pflag <> 'N' 
);
quit;

%put Process count flag: &prcs_flag_cnt;

%if &prcs_flag_cnt > 0 %then %do;
%let rflag = Y;
%end;

%else %do;
%let rflag  = N;
%end;

%end;

%else %do;
%let rflag = N;
%end;

%end;

%else %do;
%let rflag = N;
%end;
```

I am basically checking if a particular execution is a fresh execution or a restarted one and populate the rflag accordingly (Y for restart, N for fresh start). Firstly I am checking if restart_flg is Y, if so, I check the existence of a SAS dataset (flags2), and if it exists, I check if any of the records exist with "flag = 1 and pflag <> 'N'" condition and then populate Y or N for rflag accordingly. If the restart_flg is N in first place, the rflag is set to N.

I find the way multiple if conditions written in the code to be less elegant. Is there any better way of writing this if-else condition or accomplishing this functionality?

Thanks!

Comment: how about using a [select](http://v8doc.sas.com/sashtml/lgref/z0201966.htm)

Answer (score 0):

sure, easy enough:

```
%if &restart_flg = Y %then %do;
  %if %sysfunc(exist(&library.f2)) %then %do;
    proc sql;
    Connect to xxxxx as dbcon (user=xx pw=xx server=xx port=xxx database=xxxxx);
    select * into :prcs_flag_cnt from connection to dbcon  (
      select count(1)::smallint
      from &library.f2
      where flag = 1 and pflag <> 'N' 
    );
    quit;

    %put Process count flag: &prcs_flag_cnt;

    %if &prcs_flag_cnt > 0 %then %let rflag = Y;
    %else %let rflag  = N;
  %end;
  %else %let rflag = N;
%end;
%else %let rflag = N;
```

alternatively:

```
%let prcs_flag_cnt=0;
%if &restart_flg = Y and %sysfunc(exist(&library.f2)) %then %do;
  proc sql;
  Connect to xxxxx as dbcon (user=xx pw=xx server=xx port=xxx database=xxxxx);
  select * into :prcs_flag_cnt from connection to dbcon  (
    select count(1)::smallint
    from &library.f2
    where flag = 1 and pflag <> 'N' 
  );
  quit;
  %put Process count flag: &prcs_flag_cnt;
%end;

%if &prcs_flag_cnt > 0 %then %let rflag = Y;
%else %let rflag  = N;
```